# Kotlin - KClass<*> from KType

Tags: kotlin, reflection

In Kotlin, I can obtain a `KType` from a `KClass<*>` like so:

```
Int::class.createType()
```

> kotlin.Int

How do I do the reverse and obtain the `KClass<Int>` from a `KType` representing a `kotlin.Int`?

Comment: I think this is the one: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/jvm-erasure.html

Comment: Here is a bit of explanation on the subject https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/why-is-kclass-not-a-ktype/3341/2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`KType.classifier`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/classifier.html) for this:

```
val intType : KType = Int::class.createType()
val intClassifier : KClassifier? = intType.classifier
assertEquals(Int::class, intClassifier) // true
```

Note that since 1.3.40 you can also (at least on the JVM) use the experimental [`typeOf<Int>()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/type-of.html) to get your [`KType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/index.html). You may want to have a look at the [1.3.40-announcement](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/06/kotlin-1-3-40-released/) to see whether that might be useful to you.

Speaking of the JVM: on the JVM you can also use [`KType.jvmErasure`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/jvm-erasure.html) to get the actual class as also [marstran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137489/marstran) pointed out in the comment.

Comment: Thanks Roland. I saw the announcement on `typeOf<Int>()`...super cool! Basically a kotlin _esque_ equivalent of `typeof` in C#.

Comment: ^ I should have said `typeOf<T>()` if I was being precise. Presumably the implementation is just something like `inline fun <reified T> typeOf() = T::class.createType()` ?

Comment: @series0ne, no, the implementation is more sophisticated. With `SomeType::class.createType()`, you lose the information about the type arguments and nullability of `SomeType`. In comparison, `typeOf<SomeType>()` retains that information because a compiler intrinsic is used, and the type information is somewhat hard-coded into the bytecode. For example, take a look at the bytecode the compiler emits for `typeOf<MutableList<Int?>?>()`.