# How do I get the KClass of a constructor parameter in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I want to create some sort of dependency injection system taking a list of classes that need to be instantiated to create a sort of dependency tree. For that I want to take all the classes and first of all find their "external dependencies" (the classes that are not contained in the tree).

**My problem is**: In kotlin, the parameters of a constructor (KFunction) are saved as types of which I don't know how to get the classes which I really need.

So the question is: How can I get the actual KClasses of constructor parameters in kotlin?

Comment: Do you realise that not all parameters are represented by classes? For example, a parameter could be of a type parameter, which is not a class.

Comment: What would that look like in a constructor?

Comment: For example: `data class Foo<T>(val x: T)` What class do you want to get for the parameter `x`?

Comment: So is there even a way of knowing what other classes a class depends on in its constructor?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "depends on". Would you be happy if the result was `Any::class`, for `class Foo<T>(x: T)`? For multiple bounds like `class Foo<T>(x: T) where T : Comparable<T>, T: Serializable`, would you be happy if the result is `Comparable::class` and `Serializable::class`?

Comment: Since I am not going to deal with generic classes anyway I would already be happy if an exception or something like that were thrown. In other words I don't care about such cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin - KClass<\*> from KType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56686420/kotlin-kclass-from-ktype)

Comment: See the link above. Note that `KClass` implements `KClassifier`, and you can just cast the `KClassifier` you get from `KType.classifier` to `KClass` if you don't care about `KTypeParameter`s, which is the other type that implements `KClassifier`. Alternatively, use `jvmErasure` if you are on the JVM, as the link says.